# how to connect multiple Parse servers to the same mongodb?

Tags: parse-server

I would like to have two separate Parse servers (configured with a different app ID) connect to the same mongodb, so they can see the same set of users, so that I can create 2 different apps that share the same userbase.

Is this something Parse would support? Are there any expected conflicts or config caveats? I was unable to find info about this on Parse's github..

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing to do, besides setting the database URL option to the same value on both servers, and that your database is accessible from both servers.

I'm not sure why you would need two different applicationId's as you want the same data and likely, logic running on both apps.

Comment: example: when a user wants to reset a password, I want the password website, and any password/signup emails to be issued from a separate url and email.

Comment: Ok in this sense, you’ll probably need to explore running multiple server instances on different ports and using nginx as a reverse proxy. If you are familiar with docker this can help too. Basically, uou’ll Need to share all the configuration, but the small different parts. Do you plan to host them all on the same domain or different domains?

Comment: assume I can set up new servers linked to a new domain. I can decide to either use or not use separate app IDs (if there's a problem, I can use same app ID), I just want the email/domain that users see, to be different & understand other impact I might encounter... thanks!

Comment: So as mentioned, you’ll need multiple parse-server processes, running on different ports (same machine) or different machine. Each parse-server process will have it’s own configuration, including publicServerURL, email etc... BUT, the same databaseURL. Does it make sense?

Comment: @sagiman it's now a year since you asked this question, we have a similar requirement.. did you get it working (without any issues)?

Answer (score 0):

No, Parse Server does not support sharing classes between applications.

What you could do is have one of the instances or maybe a third one handle authentication and store your user information. I am pretty sure this would mean you will have to manually set user info on your requests and objects to save on the other two instances.

Another option is for each of the instances have an afterSave hook on the user class that saves and updates the info at the other instance. This seems easier to do and maintain.

I would choose the second option.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any example or specific reason as to where a conflict would occur between the 2 servers, over the same db?